# Converting sequence (represented in a recursive form) with dependence on only one predecessor into an explicit formula

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I am a former student and really enjoy solving tasks that fall into my fields of interest. At a meeting with one he had an interesting task, which I have written below in a formula. The task was as follows: take any odd number and shifted it by one digit, if it was odd, then add the initial number shifted by one digit to it in the future. The real question was then what the result would be after $n$ steps. This task sounded like fun and for a few weeks now I've been thinking about how to solve this task, but haven't really come to a conclusion yet.

Consider the following formula

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{1+(-1)^{a_n}}{2}b-\frac{1+(-1)^{a_n+1}}{4}.$$

I need to convert the above formula into an explicit formula with $a_0=2b+1$ for some arbitrary integer $b$. One approach I have tried is to form $a_{n+2}$ and then derive an explicit formula from it:

$$\begin{eqnarray}a_{n+2} &=& \frac{a_{n+1}}{2}+\frac{1+(-1)^{a_{n+1}}}{2}b-\frac{1+(-1)^{a_{n+1}+1}}{4} \\
&=& \frac{a_n}{4}+\frac{1+(-1)^{a_n}}{4}b-\frac{1+(-1)^{a_n+1}}{8}+\frac{1+(-1)^{a_{n+1}}}{2}b-\frac{1+(-1)^{a_{n+1}+1}}{4}
\end{eqnarray}$$

From this, the following formula can now be concluded:

$$a_{n}=\frac{a_0}{2^n}+\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1+(-1)^{a_k}}{2\cdot2^{n-k}}b-\frac{1+(-1)^{a_k+1}}{4\cdot2^{n-k}}\right)$$

Possibly one could come to an explicit formula here, however I do not get the predecessors out of the exponents in the sum, although these distinguish only between even and odd.

Some additional notes that may help:

$b=1$:
The Sequence is 3,1,0,**1,0**,...

$b=2$:
The Sequence is 5,2,3,1,0,**2,3,1,0**,....

$a_i=2\cdot b$ can never happen

$a_n \le 2^{\lfloor \log(b)\rfloor+2}$, because of that there has to be a subsequence that is repeated at some point

$a_1=b$

In some cases it is possible for a specific $b$ to generate a function.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you get when $ b = 1$? What about $ b = 2$?

Comment: @CalvinLin thank you, thats totaly right

Comment: @AnneBauval Fixed Title

Comment: @CalvinLin tried to rewrite the fractures with something else, also when calculated $a_{n+2}$ and $a_{n+3}$ to find some pattern.

For b=1 its getting pretty boring and its starting to alternate between 1 and 0.
For b=2 i dont notice anything special.
At some point it starts to repeat itself what has to happen because of ${a_n} <= 2^{ceil(log(b)+1)+1}-1$

Comment: I seem to be gettin that $a_i = 2b$ always, and it follow by substituting in $a_n = 2b$ into the expression to get $ b + b - 0$. Can you check again?

Comment: @CalvinLin i had some mistake, thank you, fixed that its easy to see that $a_{i}=2b$ can never happen

Comment: Did you really don't see the pattern for $b=2$?

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457197/converting-sequence-represented-in-a-recursive-form-with-dependence-on-only-on

Answer (score 0):

[Note: OP changed the question from $a_0 = 2b$ to $a_0 = 2b+1$. This addresses the former version.]

By trying small cases, one easily makes the guess that $ a_i = 2b$.

This is easily verified from

$$  \frac{2b}{2 } + \frac{ 1 + (-1)^{2b} } { 2} b - \frac{ 1 + (-1)^{2b+1} } { 4} = b + b - 0 = 2b. $$